Population a large table in random order efficiently
Given a 2D table consisting for example of
struct POD
{
    int someData;
    float someOtherData;
    bool someMoreData;
    // Other basic numerical types...
};

How would I efficiently populate a 2D table with such value. Specificly ( for example in a multi threaded context ) in a random order, where entire rows are filled in at a time.
In C, I would:

Count and assign indices in the table
Actually allocate the array
Any thread can calculate where it needs to write, from a base pointer and its index
And treat that memory as a smaller sub array where it can write into.

How would I translate this efficiently into C++ ideally using STL containers. Some additional remarks/questions:

The main concern I have is that the STL libraries initialize allocated memory, I don't know how much overhead this would cause. ( Example table size 50000x20x(16bytes) )
Idealy, it would be nice to reuse a table that is no longer needed when creating a new one
Any solution should support the ability to used aligned storage as well.

As a note: std::vector::reserve + std::vector::emplace_back would not work as the table should support random order initialization/population.

I'm sure that if you give your POD type a default constructor (i.e. X() = default;, then the STL will not initialise the allocated memory either. The constructor calls will be optimized away. (STL is an anachronistic term BTW)

Out of intrest, why is STL considered an anachronistic term and what is its modern name?

X() = default; seems not correct. X(){} seems to produce the correct results from testing. https://godbolt.org/z/ehE9WbznY

where by "correct results" you mean "does not initialize anything". As long as you know what you're doing...

What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ standard library"?

Just do the simplest thing that can work:
using LargeTable = std::vector<std::vector<POD>>;

void fillRow(LargeTable& large_table, int row) {
  std::vector<POD> temp;
  temp.reserve(20); // Allocates memory but does not initialize it.
  // call temp.emplace_back or temp.push_back 20 times
  large_table[row] = std::move(temp);
}

At the top level, do:
LargeTable large_table(50000);

and somehow call fillRow 50000 times over however many threads you want.
The residual overhead is for constructing std::vector<POD> 50000 times, but this is a simple zero-initialization that Clang can flatten to a single memset call, while GCC writes out the elements one by one.
